Static in django
How can I add a static template tag for this in Django? {% static %}
<body style="background-image: url('path') "></body> 

I have tried this, but it is not working.

<body style="background-image: url('{% static "path" %} ') "></body> 



Can you please add what doesn't work? Show what the error is you're getting so we can help you out :)

Could you please check your have loaded the static template tag at the top of your template. Also please check the path of image made on the frontend. You can also share the URL of the webpage if it is live.
{% load static %}

Yes, I have loaded the statics.  It doesn't give me an error but it does not work

What does "it does not work" mean? Open the devtools and check the rendered HTML, what does it show? Please share a [mre] that we can run to reproduce your problem.
